# I don't have access to the gallery in The Sims 4

Tags: the-sims-4

I bought the game 2 years ago and I never had access to the gallery. I read on the internet that some people can't access the gallery and have an error message when they try to enter it, but for me I don't even have the gallery icon. I don't know what to do. I tried everything written online but nothing works.

Comment: What are the things you have tried? It's good to include them so you don't get answers offering the same solutions here.

Comment: i tried changing the childs account into an adult one(but already had an adult one) , looking in the parameters to put the option : "use origins during gameplay"

Comment: Have you checked that the game is completely up-to-date?